# SP13: Custom List Add Item Redirect

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, javascript, custom-list

This is possible with a SharePoint Survey, but not sure how it's done using a Custom List.  I have a custom list and when someone adds an item after they click 'save' it opens to the list library (normal function of SharePoint).  But instead of viewing the list library after selecting 'save', I want them to be directed to a thank you page (similar to a survey but without using a survey).

Does anyone know how to redirect to  a "thank you" page after clicking 'save' instead of seeing the list library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done by appending "Source" querystring parameter to the newform.aspx url. For example, on a page add a link to the custom list newform.aspx in this way

```
<a href="http://site/lists/yourlist/newform.aspx?Source=http://site/sitepages/thankyoupage.aspx">Click here to add new item</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, HarryB!  This is great, but I must be doing something incorrect.  Created a button and added the custom list newform link (as you suggested), but "Something Went Wrong" appears.  Do you know why this would happen?  Thanks!

Comment: The href attribute has two URLs - newform.aspx url and the thankyoupage.apsx url. Please check that both urls are correct by typing them in the browser address box one by one. You can also look in the ULS logs to find out the reason behind the error.